Client-Server Connection Timeout in WSL
I am working on a project where I have a TCP server running inside WSL2 on a Windows machine, and I'm trying to connect to this server from a client running on another machine on the same local network. Despite several attempts, the connection keeps timing out.
Here are the steps and configurations I've tried so far:
Server Code (C++):
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

struct MessageHeader {
    uint8_t header_length;
    uint8_t message_type;
    uint32_t timestamp;
    uint16_t sender_id;
    uint16_t receiver_id;
    uint32_t message_id;
    uint16_t payload_length;
    uint16_t checksum;
};

uint16_t calculateChecksum(const uint8_t* data, size_t length) {
    uint32_t sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        sum += data[i];
    }
    return static_cast<uint16_t>(~sum);
}

void handleClient(int client_fd) {
    MessageHeader header;
    while (read(client_fd, &header, sizeof(header)) > 0) {
        switch (header.message_type) {
            case 1: // ON_REQ
                cout << "Received online status request" << endl;
                MessageHeader response;
                response.header_length = sizeof(MessageHeader);
                response.message_type = 2; // ON_RES
                response.timestamp = static_cast<uint32_t>(time(nullptr));
                response.sender_id = header.receiver_id;
                response.receiver_id = header.sender_id;
                response.message_id = header.message_id;
                response.payload_length = 0;
                response.checksum = calculateChecksum(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&response), sizeof(response) - sizeof(response.checksum));
                send(client_fd, &response, sizeof(response), 0);
                break;
            case 3: { // CHAT
                cout << "Received chat message" << endl;
                char* payload = new char[header.payload_length];
                read(client_fd, payload, header.payload_length);
                cout << "Message: " << string(payload, header.payload_length) << endl;
                delete[] payload;
                // Send ACK
                MessageHeader ack;
                ack.header_length = sizeof(MessageHeader);
                ack.message_type = 4; // ACK
                ack.timestamp = static_cast<uint32_t>(time(nullptr));
                ack.sender_id = header.receiver_id;
                ack.receiver_id = header.sender_id;
                ack.message_id = header.message_id;
                ack.payload_length = 0;
                ack.checksum = calculateChecksum(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&ack), sizeof(ack) - sizeof(ack.checksum));
                send(client_fd, &ack, sizeof(ack), 0);
                break;
            }
            default:
                cerr << "Unknown message type received" << endl;
                break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int server_fd, client_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);

    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) {
        cerr << "Socket creation error" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))) {
        cerr << "Setsockopt error" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Bind to all network interfaces
    address.sin_port = htons(8080);

    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address)) < 0) {
        cerr << "Bind failed" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) {
        cerr << "Listen failed" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Server listening on port 8080" << endl;

    if ((client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen)) < 0) {
        cerr << "Accept failed" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    handleClient(client_fd);

    close(client_fd);
    close(server_fd);
    return 0;
}


Client Code (C++):
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <cerrno>

using namespace std;

struct MessageHeader {
    uint8_t header_length;
    uint8_t message_type;
    uint32_t timestamp;
    uint16_t sender_id;
    uint16_t receiver_id;
    uint32_t message_id;
    uint16_t payload_length;
    uint16_t checksum;
};

uint16_t calculateChecksum(const uint8_t* data, size_t length) {
    uint32_t sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        sum += data[i];
    }
    return static_cast<uint16_t>(~sum);
}

void sendOnlineStatusRequest(int sock) {
    MessageHeader header;
    header.header_length = sizeof(MessageHeader);
    header.message_type = 1; // ON_REQ
    header.timestamp = static_cast<uint32_t>(time(nullptr));
    header.sender_id = 1;      // Example sender ID
    header.receiver_id = 2;    // Example receiver ID
    header.message_id = 12345; // Example message ID
    header.payload_length = 0;
    header.checksum = calculateChecksum(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&header), sizeof(header) - sizeof(header.checksum));

    send(sock, &header, sizeof(header), 0);
}

void sendChatMessage(int sock, const string& message) {
    MessageHeader header;
    header.header_length = sizeof(MessageHeader);
    header.message_type = 3; // CHAT
    header.timestamp = static_cast<uint32_t>(time(nullptr));
    header.sender_id = 1;      // Example sender ID
    header.receiver_id = 2;    // Example receiver ID
    header.message_id = 12346; // Example message ID
    header.payload_length = message.size();
    header.checksum = 0; // Initial checksum

    size_t total_size = sizeof(header) + message.size();
    uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t[total_size];
    memcpy(buffer, &header, sizeof(header));
    memcpy(buffer + sizeof(header), message.c_str(), message.size());
    header.checksum = calculateChecksum(buffer, total_size);
    memcpy(buffer, &header, sizeof(header));

    send(sock, buffer, total_size, 0);
    delete[] buffer;
}

void handleServerResponse(int sock, atomic<bool>& running) {
    MessageHeader response;
    while (running) {
        int bytesRead = read(sock, &response, sizeof(response));
        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            switch (response.message_type) {
                case 2: // ON_RES
                    cout << "Received online status response" << endl;
                    break;
                case 4: // ACK
                    cout << "Received ACK for message ID: " << response.message_id << endl;
                    break;
                case 5: // NACK
                    cerr << "Received NACK for message ID: " << response.message_id << endl;
                    break;
                case 6: // ERR
                    cout << "Received error message" << endl;
                    break;
                default:
                    cerr << "Unknown message type received" << endl;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int sock = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    atomic<bool> running(true);

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        cerr << "Socket creation error" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(8080);

    // Replace with the Windows host IP address obtained from `ipconfig`
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.100"); // Example IP, replace with actual IP

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        cerr << "Connection failed: " << strerror(errno) << endl; // Print the error message
        return -1;
    }

    sendOnlineStatusRequest(sock);

    thread responseThread(handleServerResponse, sock, ref(running));

    string message;
    while (running) {
        cout << "Enter message: ";
        getline(cin, message);
        if (message == "quit") {
            running = false;
            break;
        }
        sendChatMessage(sock, message);
    }

    running = false;
    responseThread.join();
    close(sock);

    return 0;
}


Network Configuration:

Both the client and server machines are on the same network
I verified the server's IP address using 'ipconfig'

Port Forwarding in WSL2:

I set up port forwarding to ensure the server is accessible from outside WSL

I used 'telnet' to test the connection from my client to server but it keeps timing out.
telnet 172.31.136.105 8080
I also pinged the server IP from the client but it stays stuck on this line:
PING 172.31.128.1 (172.31.128.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
What could be causing these timeouts to happen? Is it because both the client and server are running in a WSL environment?
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions, especially from anyone who's done network programming before!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include all your console output as plain text in code fences.

Can you try running your client on a machine (if available) whose IP is 172.31.128.x?

Please don't edit answers into the question or say that it's been solved, the fact that you've posted an answer implies that

Just solved this! If anyone else is having this issue, make sure you're connecting to the correct IP (in this case wireless LAN for me, not ethernet which uses a different IP address)
